# Add free text to excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, sas, ods

I have the following SAS program which creates an excel workbook and puts the output of a `proc tabulate` in several sheets/registers (`BY var1`):

```
ODS EXCEL FILE="/projects/myFile.xlsx" options(
    frozen_headers="4"
    sheet_name="#byval1"
    embedded_titles="yes"
    embedded_footnotes="yes");

    PROC TABULATE DATA=table;
        BY var1;
        TITLE 'My Title';
        FOOTNOTE '© 2020 by Company';
        CLASS ...;
        TABLES ...;
    RUN;
ODS EXCEL CLOSE;
```

So my questions are:

*1. How can I add an extra sheet at the beginning where I can write some free text information (such as meta-data)

*2. How can I, directly below the table produced by proc tabulate, add some additional free text (e.g. some sentences explaining the table)?

*3. Is there a way to specify the appearance of such text elements? (e.g. text color or text size)

Comment: PROC ODSTEXT is newer and also offers some good options for placing text in files.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ODS TEXT to write text, but that does not seem to force a new sheet. Or you can use a data step with `FILE PRINT` and `PUT` statement to write text.  Or just make a simple dataset with the text and write that.  Use an extra ODS EXCEL options(...) statement to set the sheet_name.

```
%let path=/projects/;
ODS EXCEL FILE="&path.myFile.xlsx" options(sheet_name='Information');
data _null_ ;
  file print;
  put 'Hello world';
run;
ODS EXCEL options
    (frozen_headers="4"
     sheet_name="#byval1"
     embedded_titles="yes"
     embedded_footnotes="yes"
    )
;
proc print data=class; 
  by sex; 
run;
ods EXCEL close;
```

You can use additional FOOTNOTE statements to add other text below your "pages" in the PROC TABULATE.  If you need more control then you might need to switch to PROC REPORT instead of PROC TABULATE.

Look at ODS style settings for how to control the appearance of any part of this.

Comment: Unfortunately with this code the text "hello world" is put on top of the first sheet created by proc tabulate (by = variable). What I would like to have is to have text in a SEPARATE sheet at the beginning.

Comment: The ODS TEXT does not seem capable of triggering a new sheet.  Updated answer.